# Different actions for each table elements within a loop

Tags: lua

I have a table containing a variable amount of items.

table = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

I need to perform the same actions for items 1~5 and then perform a different action for item 6 and above.

How can I do that in a loop including all elements of the table?

Exemple:

For items 1-5, it will print "hello". When the loop reaches the 6th element and forward, it'd print "hello there".

Comment: Use `if` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `if` inside the loop:

```lua
local mytable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

for k,v in ipairs(mytable) do
    if k <= 5 then
        print("Hello!")
    else
        print("Hello there!")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two separate loops:

```
local mytable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

for i=1,5 do
    print("Hello!",mytable[i])
end

for i=6,#mytable do
    print("Hello there!",mytable[i])
end
```